# Compare Calculated Date with Date Dimension in MDX

Tags: date, mdx, dimension

I've the following requirement:

There's a Fund Dimension and Date Dimension and Bid Price Measure. I've to show the Fund Code, Fund Series, Fund Name in Row and Bid Price in columns for only three Days i.e Today, 7 Days Back and Yesterday. I've calculated These days. How can I show the Dates on Row and get data for only those dates?

```
 WITH
 MEMBER [DateTest].[Today] As 
FORMAT (Now(),'yyyy-MM-dd')

MEMBER [DateTest].[Yesterday] As 
FORMAT (Now()-1,'yyyy-MM-dd')

MEMBER [DateTest].[LastWeek] As 
FORMAT (Now()-7,'yyyy-MM-dd')

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Fund Bid Price 6dp - Fund Ccy] } ON COLUMNS,

  NON EMPTY { (
   Except([Fund].[Fund Code].[Fund Code].ALLMEMBERS,
             filter([Fund].[Fund Code].[Fund Code].ALLMEMBERS ,
                           (left( [Fund].[Fund Code].currentmember.name,1)="P"
                           OR left( [Fund].[Fund Code].currentmember.name,1)="Q"
                           OR left( [Fund].[Fund Code].currentmember.name,1)="W"
                           )      
                     )
              ) --Excluding fund code which are starting with 'P','Q' or 'W'       

*EXCEPT([Share Class].[Series Number].Children, [Share Class].[Series Number].&[11]  ) --Excluding "X"
   * [Fund].[Fund Name].[Fund Name].ALLMEMBERS
    * [Fund].[Fund Type].[Fund Type].ALLMEMBERS

    //* {[Business Date].[Year].&[2012],[Business Date].[Year].&[2014]}



//* ([Business Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS ) 
  ) 
  }  ON ROWS 



   FROM 
   (SELECT
   ([Business Date].[Year].&[1998] : [Business Date].[Year].&[2014] ) ON COLUMNS 

   FROM [IDM Investment Data] )
![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: How do the unique names of your days look like? This will probably be something like `[Business Date].[???].&[20140822]`.

Comment: If you have years on the rows, how are they supposed to interact with the dates on the columns? Should the dates on the column not be the date from today, but relatively to the year in the row, e. g. the last day of that year, the day before that, and the day seven weeks before the end of the year?